# max-height of a div cannot be set programatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I am trying to create a dynamic layout of divs (100% wide top to bottom) that can be opened and closed and I don't want the content to extend beyond the bottom of the page so when the open/closed state changes I run code like this:

```
// BUG: maxHeight exists in the DOM but apparently cannot be programatically set
e.style.maxHeight = h;
alert('Element ' + e.id + ' was set to have a maxHeight of ' + h + ' but actually has a maxHeight of ' + e.style.maxHeight + '.');
```

The alert always shows no change to the max-height regardless of its initial value.  This happens to be on divs.  All elements have a display style of block. The debugger is showing no exceptions.  Happens on Chrome, IE and Firefox.  Setting max-height via a style string is no problem.
I am not doing any fancy CSS such as float, position, or border-box stuff either.
Other related answers I have seen here would seem to say this should work.

Answer (score 3):

Like all dimension values in JS (height,width,top,bottom,etc.), the value(`h` in this case) must have a unit defined for this to work:

```
e.style.maxHeight = h + "px";
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/kf5naptc/)